# 32 bit app call 64 bit DLL: how to build a bridge?

Tags: com, ipc

I'm in Windows 10 64 bit

I have a 32bit app that call a 32bit plugin .dll (maybe written in C++?) an all works ok, but for many reasons I would like to use the same version of the .dll already builded in 64bit architecture. So I already have both 32 and 64 bit of the plugin .dll in the exactly same version, I have 2 .dll files (one X86 and one X64). Of coruse my app (32bit) cannot directly use the 64bit one. I wonder if is there a way (building a COM interface? IPC?a 64to32 bridge?) to use the 64bit dll in my 32bit app. I need to know step by step how to build this bridge, if tecnically possible. I don't have source code of app or .dll. Is there a utility to help to do this?

Comment: If the plugin is implemented as a COM class, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146476/connect-64bit-java-with-32bit-com-dll-using-com4j-or-jacob/43147328#43147328) answer.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ktv86wjrx8wsjz9/BFX.rar?dl=0    this is both the plugin .dll please can you tell me if is COM class?

Comment: You'll need to consult the plugin's documentation or contact the developer.